# Rails: duplicate record, some associations, other join tables only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a parent class with a lot of HABTM associations. I want to duplicate the parent class and its associations, alongside *only* the join tables for the HABTM associations so that *none* of those records themselves are duplicated.

```
class Brand < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :prices, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy

  has_one :preference

  has_and_belongs_to_many :introductions
  has_and_belongs_to_many :components
  has_and_belongs_to_many :covers
  has_and_belongs_to_many :template_categories
end
```

For example, it would clone all the original's `:prices`, its `:preference`, and only *references* to `:introductions`, `:components`, `:covers`, and `:template_categories`.

First attempt was based on [deep_cloneable](https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable), but I can't address the join tables directly.

```
def duplicate
  brand = deep_clone include: [
    :prices, :preference,
    :brands_introductions, # can't address join table
    # ... etc
  ]
  brand.save!
end
```

i.e., I want the cloned-brand to refer to the same introduction, component, etc as the original brand.

Comment: if you have a model and a has_many association + has_many through instead of a has_and_belongs_to_many, then you can treat everything the same: duplicate+change foreign key.

Comment: I have never been in the same situation of cloning records. But if the gem does not handle HABTM, just add a few lines of code to check the relationship and add manually the new records to your HABTM tables (as advised in the below answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to do it by hand. Create few services that would do the job. One for each relation.